# Deriving the angular momentum operator using passive transformations

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, coordinate-systems, commutator

So I'm following the solutions [here](https://physicsisbeautiful.com/resources/principles-of-quantum-mechanics/problems/12.2.2/solutions/hmwk11-solutions-bvxycgc.pdf/cxhMHMEdwKYcUrcHVpKidA/).

For exercise 12.2.2, I'm not quite sure why the commutator relations aren't
$$[X,L_z]=i\hbar\frac{\partial L_z}{\partial p_x}-L_zi\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial p_x}=-i\hbar Y$$
Even though the $\partial$ in the second middle term isn't acting on anything, it would act on something if we right multiplied a function right?  Why is it just ignored in the solution when it would have an effect?  Furthermore, is it valid to be using different bases for the LHS and RHS of the equation?  I realize the objects they're describing are the same but when we are working in a specific basis don't both sides need to be of that basis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a notation misunderstanding. The derivative in the operator $\frac{\partial~L_z}{\partial p_x}$ you've written should also act on something on the right. I suggest rewriting the above expression using:
\begin{align}
\left[x,L_z\right] f
&= - i \hbar \left[ \frac{\partial}{\partial p_x}(L_z f) - L_z\frac{\partial}{\partial p_x}(f) \right] \\
&= -i \hbar \left[ \left(\frac{\partial~ L_z}{\partial p_x}\right)f + L_z\left(\frac{\partial~ f}{\partial p_x}\right) - L_z\left(\frac{\partial ~ f}{\partial p_x}\right) \right]\\
&= -i \hbar \frac{\partial~L_z}{\partial p_x} f.
\end{align}

Then it becomes clear that we are not ignoring any term and that indeed
\begin{align}
i \hbar \frac{\partial~L_z}{\partial p_x} = -i \hbar y.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

You can write the commutator relation on either basis. In the link, You shared it's done without choosing any particular basis and thus it's much more concrete.

In momentum basis, the angular momentum and position operator given by
$$X\rightarrow i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial p_x}$$
$$L_z\rightarrow \left(i\hbar \frac{\partial }{\partial p_x}-i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial p_y}p_x\right)$$
Being lazy, From now on I'll use $\partial_{p_x}$ for $\partial/\partial p_x$ and so on.
\begin{align*}
[X,L_z] &\rightarrow i\hbar \partial_{p_x}\{i\hbar \partial_{p_x}p_y-i\hbar \partial_{p_y}p_x\}-\{i\hbar \partial_{p_x}p_y-i\hbar \partial_{p_y}p_x\}i\hbar \partial_{p_x}\\
&\rightarrow (i\hbar)^2\partial_{p_x}^2p_y-(i\hbar)^2\partial_{p_xp_y}p_x-(i\hbar)^2\partial_{p_x}p_y\partial_{p_x}+(i\hbar)^2\partial_{p_y}p_x\partial_{p_x} 
\end{align*}
Now use the fact
$$\partial_{p_x}p_y\partial_{p_x}\rightarrow p_y\partial^2_{p_x}\ \ \ \&\ \ \ \partial_{p_y}p_x\partial_{p_x}\rightarrow p_x\partial_{p_yp_x}$$
Also
$$\partial_{p_xp_y}p_x=\partial_{p_x}p_x\partial_{p_y}=\partial_{p_y}+p_x\partial^2_{p_xp_y}$$
$$[X,L_z]\rightarrow -(i\hbar)^2\partial_{p_y}\rightarrow -i\hbar Y $$
As required.